# Using the content of a Wordpress page elsewhere in the Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

Hello I would like to use the content of a number of Wordpress pages in different areas of my template. As an example, the content of the about page being output into the sidebar.

Now I know that I can use the loop with a new query to query just that specific page. But am wondering if there is a simpler method of doing that, that doesn't require me to reset my previous query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div id="widget">
    <?php echo substr(get_post($page_id)->post_content, 0, 50); ?> 
</div>`

You could add something like this into your sidebar (within your theme folder). Replace $page_id with the ID of your About page.